# mutable thread vs non-const method

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I have a class where I want to call a method in a thread.

My methods don't modify the class attributs so I expect them to be const, but they instantiate a thread, so they can't.

What is the best choice between putting the std::thread mutable, remove the const because of the thread, **edit : or using detached threads** ?

```
class ValidationSound
{
public:
    [... CTOR DTOR ...]

    void emitSuccessSoundAsync() const 
    {
        if(m_thread.joinable())
        {
          m_thread.join();
        }
        m_thread = std::thread(&ValidationSound::emitSound, this, std::cref(m_bipsParameters.first));
    };

    void emitFailureSoundAsync() const
    {
        if(m_thread.joinable())
        {
          m_thread.join();
        }
        m_thread = std::thread(&ValidationSound::emitSound, this, std::cref(m_bipsParameters.second));
    };

    void emitSound(const BipParameters& bipParam) const
    {
        //BIP BIP THE BUZZER
    };

private:
    std::pair<BipParameters, BipParameters> m_bipsParameters;
    mutable std::thread m_thread;
};
```

Comment: How does your beeping work? If it just beeps for some given time, maybe a better way would be to detach the thread, don't you think?

Comment: The BipParameter contains the number of bips, the duration, and the interval between every bips emitSound call the buzzer with these parameters. What do you mean by `detach the thread` ?

Comment: `auto t = std::thread(&ValidationSound::emitSound, this, std::cref(m_bipsParameters.second));  
t.detach();`

Comment: I generally  advise against usage of detached threads. They often lead to nasty coredumps.

Comment: This question is purely opinion-based question in my view.

Comment: ah ok, I had not heard of detached threads, this might be a solution.

Comment: Do beware that if you use detached threads, the next beeps may interfere with previous set of beeps.

Comment: Yep, I have understand, and I can't ensure that the first call will be terminated before launching the second one. So it's not the best solution here.

Comment: shouldn't each sound producer be its own state machine (possibly running in a second thread) so you can signal it to stop?

Comment: Do you want to be able to emit more than one sound at a time? If so, then the design of having just one single thread object seems broken.

Comment: No I don't. I use thread only because bips can take a while, and I don't want to block the execution for it.

Comment: One solution would of course be to have a different interface - create a thread, and then send a message to that thread, which plays the sound. If the message queue has only one slot, it would/should block until the thread is ready to take the next message.

Comment: Ok, yes indeed it's a pretty nice solution. It require a thread which is always up and listening though, so it require a bit more of ressources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My methods don't modify the class attributs so I expect them to be const, but they instantiate a thread, so they can't.

But your methods *do* modify class attributes.  Your std::thread is a class attribute and once any of your methods are called, that attribute will change (begin running) and *continue* to change state even after the methods have exited.

> What is the best choice between putting the std::thread mutable, remove the const because of the thread, edit : or using detached threads ?

In this case, I'd recommend removing the const from method signatures.  Const just confuses the interface and could fool users into thinking it's thread-safe.  If the methods were mutex protected and blocked for the duration of the thread execution time, you could make a stronger argument for mutable and const, but given your current implementation I wouldn't.

Edit: Said another way, imagine you've gone ahead and created a single `const` instance of you `ValidationSound` class.  It would be very easy for a user of this class to call your instance in a way that creates many threads all playing different sounds interleaved at different times.  Is that how you'd envision a const instance of this class behaving?  It's certainly not how I'd envision it looking purely at the interface.